# Always run Unit Tests in Release mode

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, configuration

I've got a method that contains logic that varies between release mode and debug mode. It is not advanced at all, but i still want a unit test for it, since my application will be used in a bigger picture and i want to redirect the user to other sites if it is not used in release mode.

And now to my question, is there any way to force the unit test to run in Release Mode? I don't want to manually change build configuration for every time i want to run my unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running your unit tests in Release mode you can create a test seam so you can control which behavior you want to elicit. You might be able to something like this:

```
public class Foo {

    public int Bar() {
      if (IsDebugModeEnabled()) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    }

    public boolean IsDebugModeEnabled() {
      #if DEBUG
      return true;
      #else
      return false;
      #endif
    }   
}
```

This way you have a couple of options to test both paths of your logic. You can create a subclass `Foo` and override `IsDebugModeEnabled` or use a partial mock to directly set the return value.

Comment: Sorry for not responding, been away. That sounds like a neat solution and a more unit-test like approach! Thank you